# Flask app : error while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

The site runs with nginx and an uwsgi (flask app) and shellinabox terminal.
After every 20 or 30 minutes, the shellinabox terminal is not getting loaded and the nginx log shows this -

```
2012/05/26 14:20:27 [error] 4547#0: *117 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 192.168.122.128, server: _, request: "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:1973", host: "www.MYwebapp.org", referrer: "http://www.MYwebapp.org/login/"

2012/05/26 14:20:31 [crit] 4547#0: *105 mkdir() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy/3/00" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 192.168.122.128, server: _, request: "GET /terminal/proxy/ShellInABox.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4200/ShellInABox.js", host: "www.MYwebapp.org", referrer: "http://www.MYwebapp.org/terminal/proxy/index/"

2012/05/26 14:21:06 [error] 4547#0: *103 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream 
, client: 192.168.122.128, server: _, request: "POST /terminal/proxy/? HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4200/", host: "www.MYwebapp.org", referrer: "http://www.MYwebapp.org/terminal/proxy/index/"

2012/05/26 14:21:06 [error] 4547#0: *103 open() "/var/www/MYwebapp/templates/50x.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.122.128, server: _, request: "POST /terminal/proxy/? HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4200/", host: "www.MYwebapp.org", referrer: "http://www.MYwebapp.org/terminal/proxy/index/"

2012/05/26 14:22:31 [error] 4547#0: *136 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.122.128, server: _, request: "GET /terminal/proxy/index/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4200/index/", host: "www.MYwebapp.org", referrer: "http://www.MYwebapp.org/terminal/"

2012/05/26 14:22:31 [error] 4547#0: *136 open() "/var/www/MYwebapp/templates/50x.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.122.128, server: _, request: "GET /terminal/proxy/index/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4200/index/", host: "www.MYwebapp.org", referrer: "http://www.MYwebapp.org/terminal/"
```

I tried to put sometime-out values ... nothing helped so far.
As I'm pretty much new to nginx/uwsgi/shellinabox, I'm currently stuck with this.
Here is my nginx.conf file -

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/MYwebapp_access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    
    #
    # The default server
    #
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  _;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location /terminal/proxy {
          rewrite           ^/terminal/proxy/(.*)$ /$1 break;
          proxy_pass        http://localhost:4200/index;
          proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      #proxy_read_timeout 3000;
      uwsgi_connect_timeout 6000;
      uwsgi_read_timeout 6000;
      uwsgi_send_timeout 6000;
        }

        location / { try_files $uri @MYwebapp; }
        location @MYwebapp {
          include     uwsgi_params;
          uwsgi_pass  localhost:1973;
      uwsgi_connect_timeout 6000;
      uwsgi_read_timeout 6000;
      uwsgi_send_timeout 6000;
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
            root   /var/www/MYwebapp/templates;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /var/www/MYwebapp/templates;
        }

        
    }

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


2012/05/26 14:21:06 [error] 4547#0: *103 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream 
, client: 192.168.122.128, server: _, request: "POST /terminal/proxy/? HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4200/", host: "www.MYwebapp.org", referrer: "http://www.MYwebapp.org/terminal/proxy/index/"
2012/05/26 14:21:06 [error] 4547#0: *103 open() "/var/www/MYwebapp/templates/50x.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.122.128, server: _, request: "POST /terminal/proxy/? HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4200/", host: "www.MYwebapp.org", referrer: "http://www.MYwebapp.org/terminal/proxy/index/"

2012/05/26 14:22:31 [error] 4547#0: *136 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.122.128, server: _, request: "GET /terminal/proxy/index/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4200/index/", host: "www.MYwebapp.org", referrer: "http://www.MYwebapp.org/terminal/"
2012/05/26 14:22:31 [error] 4547#0: *136 open() "/var/www/MYwebapp/templates/50x.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.122.128, server: _, request: "GET /terminal/proxy/index/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4200/index/", host: "www.MYwebapp.org", referrer: "http://www.MYwebapp.org/terminal/"
```

Comment: Is your uwsgi worker queue full?

Comment: Not sure, but restarting the service worked fine. thanks!